# LNK 2019 error with namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am trying to compile a project in C++, VS 2012, and I am running into a LNK 2019 error. I have #ifndef macros on all my header files. I think it is getting confused about a file I included in a namespace that holds helper functions, as I am new to using namespaces and am possibly using them wrong. It looks like this:

Foo.h:

```
namespace fooSpace
{
    foo();
}
```

I include this in Foo.cpp:

```
using fooSpace;

foo ()
{
// definition of foo
}
```

I also include Foo.h in my Main.cpp, where I try to use the function by saying:

```
using fooSpace;

// Other stuff

fooSpace::foo();
```

Is there anything strikingly obvious as to why I would get the linker error? Or is it nothing necessarily here, and it's probably something else I've done?

Thanks very much for any response!

Comment: Post the complete error.

Comment: I meant to upvote your comment, but I think it removed it. Please post the link you made again?

I looked at the link at I followed Version 1 as recommended, and the code compiles just fine. This may seems stupid, but can you, or anyone else, explain why adding "fooSpace::" to the beginning of my function declaration works? I thought I didn't need it specifically because I had already said "using fooSpace;" at the top of the file.

Comment: The code in the middle fragment implements `::foo`, not `fooSpace::foo`

Comment: Nevermind, here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681714/correct-way-to-define-c-namespace-methods-in-cpp-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition must be either inside the namespace

```
namespace fooSpace {
    <return_type> foo() {
        // definition
    }
}
```

or qualified to indicate that it's the function in the namespace, not another function of the same name

```
<return_type> fooSpace::foo() {
    // definition
}
```

You are instead declaring and defining a new function, with the same name, in the global namespace, and leaving `fooSpace::foo` undefined.

Comment: Someone else technically answered first, but you set it as the answer and also explained precisely why it works in this fashion. Much appreciated, friend.

Answer (score 1):

In your code,

```
    using fooSpace; // this brings the declaration fooSpace::foo() into the current scope

    foo ()  // this is a new function in the current scope, which is ::foo()
    {
        // definition of foo
    }
```

So your function `fooSpace::foo()` has no definition yet.