# Linker can't find function definition in a namespace

Tags: c++, c++11, scope, namespaces, function-declaration

I get this `/tmp/ccnL7Yz1.o: In function 'main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x70): undefined reference to 'dng::genDungeon()'
main.cpp:(.text+0xf0): undefined reference to 'dng::clrDungeon(char**)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status` error when I'm trying to compile my program. It worked great before I added namespace functions. I'm compiling it like this: `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp Dungeon.cpp`

## Dungeon.h

```
namespace dng {
    char** genDungeon();
    void clrDungeon(char**);

    class Dungeon {
    //Methods and variables
    }
}
```

## Dungeon.cpp

```
#include "Dungeon.h"

using namespace dng;
char** genDungeon() 
{
    //Stuff
}
void clrDungeon(char** dungeon) 
{
    //Another Stuff
}
/*Implementation of class methods
void Dungeon::genStart(){} -> like this */
```

## main.cpp

```
#include "Dungeon.h"

int main () 
{
    //Stuff
    auto dungeon = dng::genDungeon();
    //Stuff
    dng::clrDungeon(dungeon);
    return 0;
}
```

I also tried to make `.o` files by myself `g++ -std=c++11 -c main.cpp` `g++ -std=c++11 -c Dungeon.cpp` and then link them, but got the same error. What can be the problem?

Comment: You could have searched a bit first: [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this.  The original title smells of *duplicate*, but the question is really about a misunderstanding of `using namespace`.

Comment: @Борис Кот Такие вопросы лучше задавать на ru.stackoverflow.:)

Comment: @zenith I searched a lot but didn't find anything similar. And it seems like your link doesn't provide a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Enclose the function definitions in the namespace dng where they are declared.

```
#include "Dungeon.h"

namespace dng
{
char** genDungeon() 
{
    //Stuff
}
void clrDungeon(char** dungeon) 
{
    //Another Stuff
}
//...
}
```

Or use qualified names.

```
include "Dungeon.h"

using namespace dng;

//...

char** dng::genDungeon() 
{
    //Stuff
}
void dng::clrDungeon(char** dungeon) 
{
    //Another Stuff
}
```

Otherwise, the functions are defined in the global namespace, and as a result, you  declared four functions: two in the namespace `dng` and another two in the global namespace.

Comment: Answering obvious duplicates encourages to creating them. Do not do this.

Comment: @Mateusz Grzejek  I am sorry. I have not understood what you said.

Comment: @Mateusz Grzejek  Oh, I have understood now.:)

Comment: You don't need `using namespace dng;` in the second case.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek I don't think it is a duplicate.

Comment: @zenith  It is unknown what this module contain else.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8681714/3425536) might be helpful for deciding which convention to use. My vote goes for using qualified names.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The functions themselves are inside `dng::` so everything from `dng::` will be automatically available inside the functions.

Comment: @zenith  You have not understood. It is unknown what else follows the function definitions in the module.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Oh you mean that. Instead of "module" you usually call them source files in C++.