# No namespace when declaring a method, and no object for the method to act upon in c++

Tags: c++, namespaces

**Context**

I am looking through a large C++ codebase which isn't mine, and I came across this problem

**Problem**

Suppose we have a class (`AClass`) in a header file:

`double MethodName(anObject& obj, string s)`

and that it is defined in the in the cxx file not as:

`double AClass::AMethod(anObject& obj, string s){`

as one would expect, but rather as:

`double AMethod(anObject& obj, string s){`

Without the namespace declaration. This is the only time in the whole cxx file when such a method is defined like this. There are no static declarations on the method, and `AClass` does not inherit from any other classes.

Also, I saw how it was called, (in a totally different file, besides AClass.h and AClass.cxx) and the line looks like this:

`if(AMethod(obj1, str)>0){`

My question is, how does this even compile and run. I would expect this code to falter when compiling

**Research**

This has been a hard one to search for. Either it is so basic, that it is not directly covered, or there is something complicated going on. If this is a simple straightforward question, please direct me to a topic I can search. I have looked through these:

[Putting class declaration in .cpp file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657528/putting-class-declaration-in-cpp-file)

[Correct way to define C++ namespace methods in .cpp file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681714/correct-way-to-define-c-namespace-methods-in-cpp-file)

but they were not very pertinent. I have also tried Googling:

"c++ defining a method in cpp file"

"c++ no namespace when defining a method in cpp file"

etc, but to no avail.

**NB**

if you wish to downvote, I would appreciate it if you were to give a reason, otherwise, I will not learn. Also, if there is any more information, you require, I will do my best to fill you in

Thank You

Comment: Could you provide links to the source files you are talking about?

Comment: Unfortunately not, they are proprietary. Is there any area of the code you would like to look at?

Comment: @qasimir, without a [mcve], it's difficult to offer sensible answers.

Comment: @RSahu I understand, but I am not sure what, in this case, is pertinent to include. I suspected that It would not be an easy one to either explain, or answer, given my level of understanding of this. I will see what else is there, and edit the question

Comment: @qasimir, my only suggestion will be to go through [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and create one.

Comment: So are you saying AMethod is declared in the header file inside the class and being implemented as a global function?

Answer (score 0):

For this declaration: `double MethodName(anObject& obj, string s)`, you would not expect this: `double AClass::AMethod(anObject& obj, string s)`.  You'd expect this: `double AClass::MethodName(anObject& obj, string s)`.

The call you are referring to `AMethod(obj1, str)>0){` is only in the `.cpp` file and not in a header so it's a `.cpp`-local function; no namespace; it's a global function.  This can happen so other classes that have to include the class don't have to compile this function.  If this is the case, AMethod cannot use class members; it can only use data passed in as a variable.

Comment: I am under the impression that one provides return types in the header files, I have not seen it done otherwise. Sorry, I should have made clear, that it is used in other files completely different to the .cxx file. However, your answer makes sense, and has given me an idea...